# MySQL - Search for entries with 3 decimal places

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 7.5 million entries, and while importing some of the data a few of the column breaks messed up and the first digit of a column ended up stuck onto the end of the previous column.

For example, on a row it should say `ELWS=123.44` and `t2=17.00`, and instead it read in `ELWS=123.441` and `t2=7.00`.

This only happened in a few places.

Is there some way to search for the entries where `ELWS` ended up with 3 decimal places?  Also, all fields are double type.

Comment: are you sure you never added a 0 as the 3rd number? in that case you could use the round() function to find out...

Comment: Do you mean are there entries in t2 that are like 07.00, which would then have ended up in the database like ELWS=123.440 and  t2=7.00? If so, then no, none of the data has leading zeros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM someTable
WHERE (ELWS * 1000) % 10 != 0
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ed0a/1)

Comment: I think that worked.  Could you explain to me what the percent sign does?

Comment: It's the [Modulus operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod).  This will return any record that after multiplying by 1000 won't divide evenly into 10.